# InkCanvas manipulation event

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx

When the only InputDeviceType of InkPresenter is CoreInputDeviceTypes::Pen then InkCanvas emits the ManipulationDelta event. When I change InputDeviceType to more types, then not. Why is that?

```
InkCanvas->InkPresenter->InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes::Mouse | CoreInputDeviceTypes::Touch | CoreInputDeviceTypes::Pen;

InkCanvas->ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes::Scale | ManipulationModes::TranslateX | ManipulationModes::TranslateY;
InkCanvas->ManipulationDelta += ref new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler(this, &ClassName::OnManipulationDeltaEvent); // OnManipulationDeltaEvent does not get called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inkcanvas?view=winrt-19041#remarks) part of InkCanvas, it mentions:

> The configuration of the InkPresenter determines the pointer event
>   handling behavior of the InkCanvas. You must set
>   InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes to CoreInputDeviceTypes.None for the
>   InkCanvas to process pointer events, otherwise they are passed to the
>   InkPresenter object.

So if you set the InputDeviceTypes to Pen, when you use the mouse to stroke, then InkCanvas can process pointer events. But if you set the InputDeviceTypes to Mouse and use mouse to Stroke, InkCanvas can't process pointer events, it will be passed to the InkPresenter object. If you want to capture the the event of mouse moving, you can subscribe the [StrokeContinued](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokeinput.strokecontinued?view=winrt-19041) event.

.h:

```
void MyStrokeContinued(Windows::UI::Input::Inking::InkStrokeInput^ sender, Windows::UI::Core::PointerEventArgs^ e);
```

.cpp:

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    InkCanvas->InkPresenter->InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes::Mouse| CoreInputDeviceTypes::Pen;
    InkCanvas->InkPresenter->StrokeInput->StrokeContinued += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler< InkStrokeInput^, Windows::UI::Core::PointerEventArgs^>(this, &MainPage::MyStrokeContinued);
}

void MainPage::MyStrokeContinued(InkStrokeInput^ sender, Windows::UI::Core::PointerEventArgs^ e) {
    //do somthing
}
```